# WKWebView Javascript does not load for objects below screen - Swift

Tags: javascript, swift, wkwebview

I'm loading a local HTML & Javascript file into my `WKWebView`. The issue that I'm experiencing is that none of the Javascript is executed for objects that are anywhere below the screen when the page is first loaded. Once I scroll to see them, the Javascript still doesn't run. How do I make it where it runs for the whole page once the page first loads?

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary way to fix this. I had to use the `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` function to execute the Javascript, rather than having the reference to it in the HTML file. Although it is a good solution, it gives the page a slight delay to execute all of the Javascript things.